# Slow boot times - windows 7 on an SSD

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

I'm running windows 7 on a 500 GB sony evo 850 SSD. When my computer boots in to windows, it will stay on the windows "welcome" screen for about 30 seconds, then transition to a black screen that only shows my mouse for round about a minute to a 2 minutes. Ive run malware checks and cleaned the registry woth ccleaner, and I also disables fastboot in my bios and even reset the CMOS for good measure. booting windows in safe mode is normal (<15 seconds boot time) and after windows starts in the normal mode the SSD is still as fast as you would expect. The SSD is about half full, and the only thing Ive recently changed is installing windows 7 SP1 on the machine, which is what I think may be causing it. Is there anything else that may obviously be causing it?

To answer a comment: 16 GB of 1600 MHz ddr3 ram
It was never this slow until last night- usually a 25 second or less boot time

Comment: RAM size?  was it always this slow?  What AV suite is loaded?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file + NGENPDB folder into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze it

Comment: again, capture the trace otherwise everything is pure speculation.

Comment: I will do so, I've been busy since the original post but Ill have time to this afternoon. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install the WPR like was suggested to me earlier, but it wouldn't install correctly for whatever reason and I couldn't find an answer as to why. I ended up sleuthing more by myself, and narrowed the problem down to a third party service. As far as I can reckon this type of issue and be caused by any service refusing to start when your PC boots, but this time it happened to be the Intel Biometrics service thing. I went in to an elevated command prompt and called the command "sc delete IntelBCAservice" and my boot times dropped back down to less than twenty seconds. Sorry I never got back to you on that boot logging thing, though at least I found a solution to my problem. Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.